# How to sort a file with `jq` on two columns?

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I want to sort my JSON file using `jq` by **Id** & **Order**. How can I do that and generate a new JSON with sorted data?

I am confused how to put array element and generate complete new sorted file.

Here is the JSON file I am working with:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://api.myserver.com/v2/$metadata#Property(Id,PhotosChangeTimestamp,ModificationTimestamp,PhotosCount)",
  "@odata.count": 2,
  "value": [
    {
      "Id": "SOMETHING_9999",
      "ModificationTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:20:19.712Z",
      "PhotosChangeTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:20:19.712Z",
      "Media": [
        {
          "MediaKey": "RAN13042846",
          "MediaType": "Image",
          "Order": 2,
          "ImageWidth": 2560,
          "ImageHeight": 1707,
          "ImageSizeDescription": "2560x1707",
          "MediaURL": "https://myserver.com/images/SOMETHING_9999/4f1900bf-4ad3-4cee-aa06-1374424875b7.jpeg",
          "MediaModificationTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:19:28.792Z"
        },
        {
          "MediaKey": "RAN13042852",
          "MediaType": "Image",
          "Order": 1,
          "ImageWidth": 2560,
          "ImageHeight": 1707,
          "ImageSizeDescription": "2560x1707",
          "MediaURL": "https://myserver.com/images/SOMETHING_9999/10924c28-3c0b-4967-9080-0216f6b9b3d8.jpeg",
          "MediaModificationTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:19:28.787Z"
        }
      ],
      "PhotosCount": 2
    },
    {
      "Id": "SOMETHING_9988",
      "ModificationTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:20:19.712Z",
      "PhotosChangeTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:20:19.712Z",
      "Media": [
        {
          "MediaKey": "RAN13042846",
          "MediaType": "Image",
          "Order": 2,
          "ImageWidth": 2560,
          "ImageHeight": 1707,
          "ImageSizeDescription": "2560x1707",
          "MediaURL": "https://myserver.com/images/SOMETHING_9999/4f1900bf-4ad3-4cee-aa06-1374424875b7.jpeg",
          "MediaModificationTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:19:28.792Z"
        },
        {
          "MediaKey": "RAN13042844",
          "MediaType": "Image",
          "Order": 1,
          "ImageWidth": 2560,
          "ImageHeight": 1707,
          "ImageSizeDescription": "2560x1707",
          "MediaURL": "https://myserver.com/images/SOMETHING_9999/4f1900bf-4ad3-4cee-aa06-1374424876b9.jpeg",
          "MediaModificationTimestamp": "2023-09-01T19:19:28.792Z"
        }
      ],
      "PhotosCount": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Isn't simply using `sort_by` on both arrays doing what you want? `.value |= sort_by(.Id) | .value[].Media |= sort_by(.Order)` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BQL9MKFaulk)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: @pmf Yes, this is what I was missing - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by `.Id` and sort all inner `.Media` arrays by `.Order`:

```
.value |= (sort_by(.Id) | .[].Media |= sort_by(.Order))
```

Other forms of the same filter are possible too.

Without parentheses:

```
.value |= sort_by(.Id) | .value[].Media |= sort_by(.Order)
```

With `map`:

```
.value |= (sort_by(.Id) | map(.Media |= sort_by(.Order)))
```

Comment: Thank you -- the question is already answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf

Comment: @TahirKhalil there was no other answer posted to this question (not even a deleted answer). There are comments, but [comments are not answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294791/112968)

Comment: OK marked the answer